# c++; What does the warning "enabled by default" mean during compile?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

My code compiles without error, but what does this mean?

```
 etherate.cpp:432:11: warning: deleting array ‘unsigned char broadMAC [6]’ [enabled by default]
```

Its from this line, where I am deleting an unsigned char array;

```
delete [] broadMAC;
```

Is it OK to leave this as it is, if not, how could I improve upon this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

*How is broadMAC declared?*

From about 10 lines previous;

```
unsigned char broadMAC[6] = {destMAC[0], destMAC[1], destMAC[2], destMAC[3], destMAC[4], destMAC[5]};
```

destMAC is also an unsigned char array with values stored inside it. 
I needed to copy them out, do something with destMAC, then restore the original values; so I have declared broadMAC and wish to delete it after.

Comment: Good point, I'll add this in!

Comment: well, it's obvious now: see Luchian's answer

Comment: "enabled by default" means the compiler will generate this warning even if you haven't enabled warnings. That's because using `delete[]` on something that wasn't allocated with `new[]` is always an error, so you'll always want to be warned about it.

Comment: The declaration of broadMAC is irrelevant to this question, @Zdeslav. (Besides, the warning already tells us what its declaration is.)

Comment: "Is it OK to leave this as it is, if not, how could I improve upon this?" -- no, it isn't ok to leave it as is.  You can improve upon it by not trying to remove from the Heap an array that is stored on the Stack. :)  (ie, don't call delete on stack/automatic storage variables -- only call delete on things you allocate with new)

Comment: @RobKennedy, well since it is declared (actually defined) as an array on stack, it is definitely relevant. If it was declared as `unsigned char*` there would be no warning (I guess, I don't use GCC compilers). The reason I asked is exactly because warning seems to point that broadMac is an array on method stack, but I was not 100% as I don't use GCC, so I don't know the exact form of warnings it produces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

G++ allows to enable and disable many warnings (e.g. `-Wctor-dtor-privacy`, `-Woverloaded-virtual`, `-W...`) by specifying them on the command line. Some warnings are enabled, without the need to do so on the command line, others must be explicitly requested.

So, some warnings are:

> "enabled by default"

and some are:

> "disabled by default"

Comment: I'm not sure it ever says "disabled by default." Rather, for options that are ordinarily disabled, the compiler will print the *name of the option* that controls the display of the diagnostic in question. If you don't want the compiler to tell you about that, then use the `-fno-diagnostics-show-option` option when you compile.

Comment: Describing what "enabled by default" is without pointing out that the code invokes undefined behavior might be a bit too literal an answer.  :)

Comment: @Yakk When I wrote my answer, Luchian Grigore already provided a perfect answer for the shortcomings. So, there was and is no point in duplicating his work.

Answer (score 13):

`broadMAC` is allocated in automatic memory, like so:

```
unsigned char broadMAC[6];
```

and then you call

```
delete[] broadMAC;
```

which is wrong, since you didn't allocate it with `new[]`.

Using `delete`/`delete[]` on memory not allocated with `new`/`new[]` results in undefined behavior, and your compiler is smart enough to tell in this case.

You needn't worry about freeing the memory, it will be freed automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Luchian Grigore, this is some great info! I was really more confused by the "enabled by default" message but this is still important to know what caused my compiler to capture and generate the message, and how to mitigate it, so thank you! +1

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to free an array which you allocated in the stack, not heap. So when the variable becomes out of scope, it will free itself and you shouldn't/can't free it explicitly.

Comment: Hi @JosephH, please see my comment to Luchian Grigore, that is why I marked Olaf Dietsche as correct, but again, thanks to you also for some good knowledge! :)