# Compilation error on passing lambda expression to template function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Why can I not get the template function to accept the lambda expression?

After searching high and low -- I seriously though that this would work, but this C++ code;

```
template <typename F> int proc(const F& lam)
{
    return lam();
}
void caller()
{
    int i = 42;
    int j = proc( [&i]()->int{ return i/7; } );
}
```

An I get the following errors;

```
$ g++ x.cc
x.cc: In function ‘void caller()’:
x.cc:11:44: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
x.cc:11:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘proc(caller()::<lambda()>)’
x.cc:11:46: note: candidate is:
x.cc:3:27: note: template<class F> int proc(const F&)
```

I'm on linux using g++ 4.6.3 and 4.7.2

Does anybody know what I have to do to pass on a lambda expression as a parameter to a receiving template function? -- I don't want to use the std::function -- so my only alternative is to create an ugly functor pattern.

*Update:* Tried to declare the argument const F& lam, but without success.
*Update2:* added call to compiler...

Comment: What flags are you passing to the compiler?

Comment: None -- no flags -- update question with call to compiler...

Comment: You have to use -std=c++11 with g++ 4.7.2 or -std=c++0x with g++ 4.6.3.

Comment: Thanks -- that does the trick -- now im very confuse what the warning message of "enabled by default" means .....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13122636/951890

Comment: I agree it is confusing in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the lambda isn't an lvalue, you need to pass it by const reference:

```
template <typename F> int proc(const F& lam)
```

Make sure to use -std=c++11 with g++ 4.7.2 or -std=c++0x with g++ 4.6.3.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the problem..

x.cc:11:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘proc(caller()::<lambda()>)’

x.cc:11:46: note: candidate is:

x.cc:3:27: note: template<class F> int proc(const F&)

Comment: Thanks @Vaughn -- tried to cut-n-paste your working code -- still have same problem -- suspect it is a compiler version problem -- what version are you using?

Comment: @Soren: I'm using g++ 4.7.2

Comment: work with -std=c++11 with g++ 4.7.2 or -std=c++0x with g++ 4.6.3.