# warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I've just installed the latest version of cygwin and eclipse luna in my machine. It's working fine and I'm able to run my projects. However when I build them I got warnings I don't understand. For example, here are the warnings from a header file "Sales_item.h" which I got from the site of a book "c++ Primer":

```
warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     Sales_item() = default;
                    ^
../src/Sales_item.h:70:27: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     unsigned units_sold = 0; // explicitly initialized
                           ^
../src/Sales_item.h:71:22: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     double revenue = 0.0;
                      ^
Finished building: ..
```

What do these warnings mean? Should I do something?

Comment: Did you pass the flag `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++1y` to the compiler?

Comment: "Should I do something?" Yes - add `-std=c++11` to your compiler's command line.

Comment: Um, no, what is that? And how to do that?

Comment: Project->Properties->C++ Build->Misc Options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `-std=c++0x`, `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++1y` to your compiler flags.

You can see that the compiler says:

`defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`

Example on compiling in the terminal:

`g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -o myExe`

In Eclipse, as πάντα ῥεῖ suggested, you can do:

`Project ->Properties ->C++ Build ->Misc Options`

or, at mine Kepler Eclipse, one would right click on the project and then:

`Properties ->C++ Build -> Settings`

and in the Command textbox, you can see the compiler you are using. You can write the compiler flag there too.

For more, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394319/c-array-initializers-warnings), as suggested by Baum mit Augen.

Comment: Do I have to do this for every project?

Comment: I think yes, but If you find a way not to, let me know @user3263252. However, my small experience shows that it is not a big deal to do it for every project. :)

Comment: yes, it doesn't really do anything, it's not like those warnings prevent the c++11 codes from running. It just shocks me a little bit because I didn't encounter those warnings when I'm using mingw

Comment: Why did it say "enabled by default" if it wasn't enabled?